# I have an absurd list, via PRAW, that I would like to store in a database. End goal is to make a wordcloud

Tags: python, mongodb, matplotlib, pymongo, word-cloud

I got the top level comments from the top 25 subissions to a subreddit, the list is entirely too long for me to work with in jupyter notebook by itself.

So I want to store the data in a database, mongodb?, hopefully allowing me to continue to work without running into memory errors.

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='',
                 client_secret='',
                 password='',
                 user_agent='',
                 username='')

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('grubhubdrivers') # Change the subreddit's name here 
sub_ids = []
for submission in subreddit.top(limit = 25): # Define the limit here and filter method
    sub_ids.append(submission.id)

top_level_comments = []
second_level_comments = []
title = []
selftext = []
for sub_id in sub_ids:
    submission = reddit.submission(id = sub_id)
    title.append(submission.title) # Get submission title
    selftext.append(submission.selftext) # Get submission content
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit = None)
    for top_level_comment in submission.comments:
        top_level_comments.append(top_level_comment.body) # Get top-level comments
        for second_level_comment in top_level_comment.replies:
            second_level_comments.append(second_level_comment.body) # Get second-level comments
```

Executes Fine, then:

```
for val in top_level_comments:
 
    # typecaste each val to string
    val = str(val)

    # split the value
    tokens = val.split()
 
    # Converts each token into lowercase
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower()
 
    top_level_comments += " ".join(tokens)+" "

wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,
            background_color ='white',
            stopwords = stopwords,
            min_font_size = 10).generate(top_level_comments)

# plot the WordCloud image                      
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)

plt.show()
```

Completely blows up my computer, even when I reduce the number of submissions.

Comment: Can you define "Completely blows up my computer"? Are you alright? Are there casualties? ;-)

Comment: Using MongoDB won't help much, since you'll still need to load stuff back to memory for `WordCloud`. However, you could just dump `top_level_comments` to a pickle file and load it in your other script to process, if that helps.

Comment: @AKX memory error and a room that feels like a sauna

Comment: Also I have no idea what a pickle file is

Comment: You can use [`pickle.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) to write most any Python object into a file, and `pickle.load()` it from there afterwards. I'd recommend separating this into two regular Python scripts; one which loads your data from Reddit and saves it to a file, and another that does the postprocessing and wordclouding.

Comment: I did something similar with json dump, would it be better to use Pickle? I'm very new to this. I assume since it is then stored in a file being read, I won't run into these memory issues? The json was because I thought I need mongo, but if that's not the case that's cool.

Comment: Pickle files are smaller and faster to work with, but the concept is similar. You're also less likely to run into memory issues if you work with regular Python scripts c.f. a Jupyter notebook, since Jupyter notebooks can easily retain state from earlier cell executions and so on.

Comment: I'll give Pickle a go. My brain is, figuratively, exploding. Thanks for your help so far.